# In React, is it possible to use a child's Ajax JSON response in multiple components of the parent?

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, reactjs, fetch-api

So with an Ajax call, I know you can do it like the following to output the data:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

export default class ApiCategories extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super();
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        fetch('http://www.ajaxcall.com/page')
        .then(response => {
            if (response.ok) {
                var responseData = response.json();
                return responseData;
            } else {
                throw new Error('Something went wrong ...');
            }
        })
        .then(data => {
            this.setState({ data })
        })
        .catch (error => {
            console.log(error);
        });
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <OutputContent data = {this.state.data} />
        )
    }
}

function OutputContent({data}) {
    if (data && Array.isArray(data)) {
        let outputData = data.map((content) => {
            return (
            <div  key={content.Key}>
                <div>{content.Title}</div>
            </div>
            )
        })
        return outputData;
    } else {
        return <p>Loading Data</p>
    }
}
```

But if I want to have a parent to use these details multiple times I'm stumped.
For example, something like the below where the parent would ask a child to make an AJAX call, which returns the response. I would only make one API call, then use that data multiple times in different components, maybe by stashing the JSON object returned etc. I've tried multiple things like an import that returns null and stashing it in localStorage, but the render of the parent usually outputs before the ajax call has completed. My call doesn't necessarily need to be in the constructor, just added in this example.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import APICall from 'apiCall.js'

class OutputContent extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    // call the api and store the data
    // APICall.callData()

    this.state = { 
    itemDetails: {list items retrieved from ajax call}
    };
}

render() {
    var returnString = (
    <div className="App">
        <SelectBox listItems={this.props.data.itemDetails} /><br />
        <SelectBox listItems={this.props.data.itemDetails} /><br />
        <SelectBox listItems={this.props.data.itemDetails} /><br />
        <SelectBox listItems={this.props.data.itemDetails} /><br />
        <SelectBox listItems={this.props.data.itemDetails} /><br />
    </div>)
    return (returnString);
}
}

export default OutputContent;
```

Comment: What do you mean by "multiple times"? Do you want it to persist between browser refreshes, or do you want to use a copy of the data in another component?

Comment: See the select box example, passing that data multiple times. It doesn't need to be browser refreshes, just in another component, so that the AJAX call isn't made lots of times on one page. Question updated hopefully clarifying that.

Comment: So you want to be able to get the data once in the parent, but pass it down as props to many children where the props will continue to be used as state for each separate child?

Comment: Technically yes. Although I'd like to keep the ajax call separate, and in it's own child. (note the import in the example)

Basically the parent calls makes an ajax call on a child, which returns the JSON response, then the parent passes this to it's components. Make sense?